# Fetch special position in JSON FORMAT

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hellp every body hope all are good today ?
I need some help please ...

This is my JSON with ***const = result***  :

```
[
 { asset: 'USDT', free: '35.00', locked: '0' },
 { asset: 'USDC', free: '80.99', locked: '0' },
 { asset: 'ETH', free: '0.005', locked: '0' },
]
```

If i do **result[0].free** = (*USDT*) **35.00**
or **result[2].free** = (*ETH*) **0.005**

How can i get **free** of **asset** **name** if i always define before, without enter the number manually?

I mean something like : ***result.asset['USDC'].free*** need return > 80.99

Because if i add different currency the position gonna change and number need to change too ... :/

How can i return the good free choosed please ?

Sincerely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format your JSON data from an array of objects to a nested object. You can achieve the same using Javascript, like this:

```js
const result = [
    { asset: 'USDT', free: '35.00', locked: '0' },
    { asset: 'USDC', free: '80.99', locked: '0' },
    { asset: 'ETH', free: '0.005', locked: '0' }
];

const new_result = { asset: {} };

// Loop through the result array and structure the new_result object
result.forEach(item => {
    const { asset, free, locked } = item;
    new_result.asset[asset] = { free, locked };
});

// Formatted result as nested JSON
console.log(new_result);

// Accessing free and locked fields for USDT
console.log(new_result.asset['USDT'].free); // Output: 35.00
console.log(new_result.asset['USDT'].locked); // Output: 0

// Accessing free and locked fields for USDC
console.log(new_result.asset['USDC'].free); // Output: 80.99
console.log(new_result.asset['USDC'].locked); // Output: 0

// Accessing free and locked fields for ETH
console.log(new_result.asset['ETH'].free); // Output: 0.005
console.log(new_result.asset['ETH'].locked); // Output: 0
```

Comment: Thanks you so much its work SINCERELY really dear friends thanks you !! i'm asking if there is another way without forEach ? to make the code shortest ... ;D